# Limit problem $\lim_{T \to 0} \frac{1}{T} \int_0^T S_u du$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Consider $dS_t = \mu S_t dt + \sigma S_t dW_t$ with initial $S_0 > 0$. We may obtain that $S_t = S_0 \exp\left[(\mu - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2) t +\sigma W_t\right]$. Hence we may consider average value of $S_T$. $A(T) = \displaystyle \frac{1}{T}\int_0^T S_0 e^{(\mu - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)t + \sigma W_t} dt$.

We want to determine $\lim_{T \to 0} A(T)$.

The main problem that we can't manage substitutions like $t = Tu$, because it's SDE. We should be careful about $W_t$. I've tried to consider $\xi \stackrel{d}{=} e^{\sigma W_t}$ and obtain $\mathbb{E} \displaystyle \frac{1}{T}\int_0^T \xi e^{(\mu - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)t}dt$. But that gives me limit in $L_1$. Not actually we interested in.

Any ideas? Maybe I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental theorem of calculus shows that

$$\lim_{T \to 0} \frac{1}{T} \int_0^T f(t) \, dt = f(0)$$

for any continuous function $f$. Applying this result for $f(t):=S_0(\omega) \exp\left(t \left[\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2} \right] + \sigma W_t(\omega) \right)$ with $\omega$ fixed, we find that

$$\lim_{T \to 0}\frac{1}{T} \int_0^T S_0(\omega) \exp\left(t \left[\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2} \right] + \sigma W_t(\omega) \right) \, dt = S_0(\omega).$$

Comment: And we should use continuity of $W_t$ as I understand ?

Comment: @openspace Yes, Brownian motion has continuous sample paths (for almost all $\omega$)

Comment: "The fundamental theorem of calculus shows that", well this needs a little bit of work (by openspace maybe). What if $F(t)/t \not \to 0 $ ? for example $f(t)=t$

Comment: @TheBridge Sorry, I don't get your comment/question. This is really immediate from the [fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part). If $f(t)=t$, then $\frac{\int_0^T f(t) \, dt}{T}$ surely converges to $0=f(0)$ as $T \to 0$.

Comment: My mistake I mistook the limit to be $\infty$ My comment is irrelevant. Regards